# Output container from openmp parallel loop

Tags: parallel-processing, openmp

Which critical section style is better when collecting output container?

```
// Insert into the output container one object at a time.
vector<float> output;
#pragma omp parallel for
for(int i=0; i<1000000; ++i)
{
    float value = // compute something complicated
    #pragma omp critical
    {
        output.push_back(value);
    }
}
```

---

```
// Insert object into per-thread container; later aggregate those containers.
vector<float> output;
#pragma omp parallel
{
    vector<float> per_thread;
    #pragma omp for
    for(int i=0; i<1000000; ++i)
    {
        float value = // compute something complicated
        per_thread.push_back(value);
    }
    #pragma omp critical
    {
        output.insert(output.end(), per_thread.begin(), per_thread.end());
    }
}
```

EDIT: the above examples were misleading because they indicated that each iteration pushes exactly one item, which is not true in my case. Here are more accurate examples:

```
// Insert into the output container one object at a time.
vector<float> output;
#pragma omp parallel for
for(int i=0; i<1000000; ++i)
{
    int k = // compute number of items
    for( int j=0; j<k; ++j)
    {
        float value = // compute something complicated
        #pragma omp critical
        {
            output.push_back(value);
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
// Insert object into per-thread container; later aggregate those containers.
vector<float> output;
#pragma omp parallel
{
    vector<float> per_thread;
    #pragma omp for
    for(int i=0; i<1000000; ++i)
    {
        int k = // compute number of items
        for( int j=0; j<k; ++j)
        {
            float value = // compute something complicated
            per_thread.push_back(value);
        }
    }
    #pragma omp critical
    {
        output.insert(output.end(), per_thread.begin(), per_thread.end());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you always insert exactly one item per parallel iteration, the proper way is:

```
std::vector<float> output(1000000);
#pragma omp parallel for
for(int i=0; i<1000000; ++i)
{
    float value = // compute something complicated
    output[i] = value;
}
```

It is threadsafe to assign distinct elements of `std::vector` (which is guaranteed because all `i` are different). And there is no significant false-sharing in this case.

If you do not insert exactly one item per parallel iteration either version is basically correct.

Your first version using a `critical` in the loop can be very slow - note that if the computation is really slow, it may still be fine overall.

The per-thread container / manual reduction is generally fine. Of course it makes the order of the result non-deterministic. You could streamline this by using a user-defined reduction.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately my example was misleading: the number of items I put in the output may be different from 1. Let me update the example.

Comment: Then my last two paragraphs apply.